# What is the use of filter and chain in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, chain

`chain.doFilter(req,res);`
We used this in a servlet program. I want to know what is the use of the method `doFilter()` in a servlet?
Also what is the use of filter and chain concept in Java servlets?

Answer (score 39):

Servlet filters are implementation of the [chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

The point is that each filter stays "in front" and "behind" each servlet it is mapped to. So if you have a filter around a servlet, you'll have:

```
void doFilter(..) { 
    // do stuff before servlet gets called

    // invoke the servlet, or any other filters mapped to the target servlet
    chain.doFilter(..);

    // do stuff after the servlet finishes
}
```

You also have the option *not* to call `chain.doFilter(..)` in which case the servlet will never be called. This is useful for security purposes - for example you can check whether there's a user logged-in.

Comment: While writing my answer, I got a message that somebody already provided one. But I still kept working on my take, thinking that the provider must have missed mentioning the pattern and the link to it. But after submitting mine, I found out that I was completely wrong. +1

Comment: @Adeel Ansari anyway, you provided a link that I didn't - the one to "essentials of filters", so +1 there as well.

Answer (score 30):

**What are Filters ?**

`Filters` are used to `intercept and process requests` before they are sent to servlets(in case of request) .

***OR***

`Filters` are used to `intercept and process a response` before they are sent back to client by a servlet.

[image]

**Why they are used ?**

-Filters can perform security checks.

-Compress the response stream.

-Create a different response.

**What does doFilter() do ?**

> The `doFilter()` is called `every time` the container determines that
>   the filter should be applied to a page.

It takes `three arguments`

->*ServletRequest*

->*ServlerResponse*

->*FilterChain*

All the `functionality that your filter supposed to do` is implemented inside `doFilter()` method.

**What is FilterChain ?**

> Your `filters do not know anything about the other filters and servlet`.
>   *FilterChain* knows the `order of the invocation of filters` and `driven` by the `filter elements` you defined in the `DD`.

Answer (score 13):

Filters are there to complement Servlets. For the usage, you should read this, [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). Filters are implemented using [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility_pattern) GoF pattern.