# Java Servlet Filter that intercepts all HTML traffic

Tags: java

What method/class from a java servlet filter can I use to intercept/modify all HTML traffic before it get's displayed by the any web browser?  I have tried searching for this online but all I got was a bunch of info about how a servlet filter can intercept a servlet, a JSP or a Static File but nothing about intercepting all HTML traffic before a browser sees it.

Comment: You need to write a filter with with mapping `*/.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a chain of filters. The last filter in the chain will be executed right before the response is sent back.

[What is the use of filter and chain in servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122870/what-is-the-use-of-filter-and-chain-in-servlet)

Comment: Link is broken. This should be the one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122870/what-is-the-use-of-filter-and-chain-in-servlet