# Disabling page access via cached URL or back button after logging out(Servlets)

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, logout, session-state

**Requirement:**

I am implementing secure logout feature in my web app(Servlets-JSP based) i.e after logging out user shouldn't be able to access any pages by typing url from Cache or hitting the back button on browser,Application should redirect to login page.

**What I did:**

Based on some reading and some SO answers i started implementing this feature with Filters and this is what i did.

in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.controller.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in my Filter class doFilter() method

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
     HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
     response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
     response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 

     HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

     if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } 
     else {
            response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/login.jsp");
        }

}
```

I am using chrome,the feature is not working at all,i.e user can still access pages after logging out with URL typing or hitting back button.

Where i am doing wrong? what changes should be done to make it work.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try logging the session blocks from filter to analyze flow

Comment: I tried to debug using logger,the flow is never hitting the filter's doFilter method.

Comment: u mean when u r logged in or not,not at all?

Comment: Post full code for your filter class?Are you extending javax.servlet.Filter

Comment: You are missing chain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse); at the end of filter doFilter method

Comment: yes i extended javax.servlet.filter. i did chain.doFilter(request,response) inside "if" clause.

Comment: I added filter <url-pattern> as "/*" means it should be filtering every url right? i am not getting logging message from doFilter() not even once

Comment: please use chain.doFilter(request,response) in filter method.Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122870/what-is-the-use-of-filter-and-chain-in-servlet

Comment: I did chain.doFilter(request,response) inside if clause,should i change it's position?

Comment: Needs to be the last statement,not within any conditional block!!