# Replace scriptlet to avoid java code inside .jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I have the same Java scriptlet copied and pasted into multiple .jsp files.
I would like to replace it with a solution that's easier to maintain and has better readability

```
    <%
    if (!MediaUtil.validateAuthorization()) {
        out.println("Unauthorized");
    } else {
        String srcquery = request.getQueryString();
        if (srcquery == null) {
            srcquery = "";
        }
        User currentUser = UserService.findCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            out.println(User.MESSAGE_NO_USER);
        } else {
    %>

    <html>
    <head>
```

EDIT: I have rewritten the code using JSTL after [FrenchFigaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948881/frenchfigaro)'s answer. Final code for anyone interested is below:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!MediaUtil.validateOrganization()}">
        <c:out value="Unauthorized"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="srcquery" value="<%=request.getQueryString()%>"/>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${srcquery == null}">
                <c:set var="srcquery" value=""/>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
        <c:set var="currentUser" value="<%=UserService.findCurrentUser()%>"/>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${currentUser == null}">
                <c:out value="<%=User.MESSAGE_NO_USER%>"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <html>

                (...)

                </html>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Sounds good, go for it. If you have any problem while doing it, please explain that

Comment: You could implement a Filter that will implement the same logic. More information on filters here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122870/what-is-the-use-of-filter-and-chain-in-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the if/else part, you can use `<c:if>` or `<c:choose>`

The first one provides a single choice and no else (but two tags with opposite conditions will do the trick).

Better to use `<c:choose>` in your case.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${condition}">...</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>...</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

As for the rest, you will need to use a bean to transfer the data between your servlet and the JSP

Comment: Sounds good. But how can I reuse this in my multiple .jsp files without having to copy and paste the same code everywhere? Is there a way to put this into a function or something like that?

Comment: JSP allows the insertion of a child page inside a parent page. You can do this with `<c:import>` or `<jsp:include>`. I haven't done this in a very long time so I'm not sure how it would be done. Those are dynamic includes, which allow for the passing of parameters. You can also do a static include using `<%@include file="path/to/child.jsp" %>`. Those are less flexible, but more performant. I haven't used either in a while, so I wouldn't be the best resource on how to use them.

Comment: @LucasMendonça Re: include. Here's an example on how to do that [https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-include-action](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-include-action)

Comment: @FrenchFigaro your link respond now "503 Service Unavailable"

Comment: @936940 I tried it this instant and it works. Might have been a temporary issue on the site's end